# Finding specific range of number in java

Tags: java, list, filter, numbers, range

Here is my code to get the students who get 70 and above marks

```
public static List<List<String>> higher (List<List<String>> data, String high) {
    
  return data.stream()    
             .filter(e-> e.get(6).equalsIgnoreCase(high))
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

This is my result

```
[70]
```

May I know how to get all the student who gets 70 and above

Comment: Can you give an example how the list is structured or how you call the method?

Comment: Are you storing marks as String? It's better to store it a class for your user data and marks as Integer, either you need to parse the string to Integer and then compare with your constant value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test this:

```
public static List<List<String>> distinction(List<List<String>> data, Integer high) {

        return data.stream()
                .filter(e-> Integer.parseInt(e.get(6)) >= high)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

high should be 70

Comment: @WJS I used Integer.parseInt() so I use Integer in parameter of function. The difference between int and Integer : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-an-integer-and-int-in-java/

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this. You need to convert the string to an int for comparison. It would also be best to pass the high as an int.

```
public static List<List<String>> Distinction(List<List<String>> data, int high) {
      
      return data.stream()    
                 .filter(e-> Integer.parseInt(e.get(2)) >= high)
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have a list of lists, you need to flatmap over the `data` to get the list of lists down to a single list.

```java
int threshold = Integer.parseInt(high);
return data.stream()    
             .flatMap(d -> d.stream()) // converts list of lists to a stream of Strings of arbitrary length
             .filter(e -> Integer.parseInt(e.get(2)) >= threshold)
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Here I'm assuming your list of lists is a bunch of 3 element lists (due to the output you provide) where the 3rd indexed element (`e.get(2)`) is the score. If you convert this value to an `Integer` using `Integer.parseInt` you'll be able to compare it for filtering.